# Calling TableView BeginUpdates in numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableview backed by an NSFectchedResultsController and I'm trying to show a custom cell when I have no results from the FRC. The problem I'm running into is that BeginUpdates recalls numberOfRowsInSection. I want to keep the tableview active (rather than just displaying an image in its place) so that the user can perform a pull to refresh.

The code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if ([self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count] == 0) {
    if (!specialCellShowing) {
        specialCellShowing = TRUE;
        [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
    return 1;
}
else {
    if (specialCellShowing) {
        specialCellShowing = FALSE;
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
    return [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
}
```

}

The problem is the return 1; statement. What happens is the first time numberOfRowsInSection is called it sets specialCellShowing = TRUE and hits begin updates, which recalls numberOfRowsInSection. The begin updates instance of the method sees that specialCellShowing is true and returns 1 and exits. Now the insert call is made and then a crash occurs on endUpdates because the tableview thinks that there is 1 cell in the table, 1 cell inserted, and 1 cell previously. The other problem is I need that return 1 where it is because in subsequent calls to numberOfRowsInSection I want it to not mess with the table and just return saying I have the one custom cell.

I guess what I'm wondering is if there is a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mutate the tableview while the tableview is updating its display. You don't need to call deleteRowsAtIndex paths unless you're mutating the tableview.  You need to have a separate method: one that responds to an event and mutates the tableview's data (and perhaps calls begin/endUpdates and adds or removes rows). -numberOfRowsInSection should just inspect the backing data and return an answer.  The tableview is doing a full update at this point, so adding and removing rows in the tableview is useless at this point anyhow.

Comment: You actually can mutate it. I had some very janky code doing this a little bit ago and the inserts and deletes worked in certain situations. Should I be doing this? Probably not. I'll look into your suggestions. I think I just needed to get out of the mindset of doing what I was thinking

Comment: Don't go directly adding or removing cells in 'numberRowsInSection'. At best you're playing with fire. 

Feel free to mutate the model during numberOfRowsInSection, but the number you return will be used as the maximum index when you get the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method directly after.  MVC dictates that you should mutate the model in response to an event and then tell the view that it needs to update.  You should not mutate the model during a view update.

Comment: Completely understood. Could you possibly point me in a direction to learn more about the view update cycle (as in which methods are called in which order?). Basically it sounds like I need to listen for the update to complete, modify the table as needed, which will create my own update. Then I should be good?

Comment: Here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAPIOverview/TableViewAPIOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH4-SW2